# mod_deflate in Apache 2 produces?

Tags: mod-deflate

What is the compression mechanism that **mod_deflate** in Apache2. Is it gzip or zlib or something else?

Comment: Complex research about HTTP compression: [Lose the Wait: HTTP Compression](http://zoompf.com/blog/2012/02/lose-the-wait-http-compression "Lose the Wait: HTTP Compression")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) uses zlib.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, I also found some more literature on this, 
http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.compression/2007-07/msg00011.html